# How to assign multiple salesperson to customers?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central

This is a basic customer card:

[image]

As you can see there is a "Salesperson" linked to the customer, but in many situations customers can have multiple salespersons.

In this field I can only select one salesperson.

The problem created by this situation in the company is that sales people can't find customers that are not linked to them.

How can I assign multiple salesperson to customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your salespeople are in fixed groups e.g. person A and B handle the same group of customers and C and D handle another group of customers, you could use the `Responsibility Center` feature.

Create a Responsibility Center for each group of customers and assign it to those customers. Then set the `Sales Resp. Ctr. Filter` on the `User Setup` for each `Salesperson`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this field, obviously, you can't. You need to use some other field like department or customer group I don't know. Or if I remember correctly the was a table like ’My Customers’ where every user can build a list of customers he's interested in.